# What is a one-word opposite of "submerged" in the physical sense

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

I'm looking for a one-word opposite of "submerged". The context is a study where I'm looking into species that live below the surface and thus can be conveniently labeled as "Submerged" in my plot. However I can't find a good word to describe those found living on the surface (of a peat bog).

*Emerged* or *surficial*(?) comes to mind but since I'm not a native speaker I'm not too sure that I can use it that way.

Comment: You might find [this source](http://images.slideplayer.com/8/2388242/slides/slide_10.jpg) useful, though the only reasonable antonym of 'submerged' is probably 'non-submerged'. Organisms living on the surface would simply be labelled surface organisms.

Comment: @NVZ I'm pretty sure it hasn't converted from a noun modifier as yet.

Comment: If you want to talk about the critters living on the peat bog from the point of view of the critters living below the surface, here are some ideas: air creatures, superterranean creatures (I made that up, based on subterranean), overwater creatures (I made that up, based on underwater), turf creatures (living in the turf, or the short grass), above-surface creatures, beyond-the-edge creatures, other-side creatures, over-the-bog creatures, on-bog creatures, over-bog creatures, overbog creatures.

Comment: You could stretch the use of "surfactants" for some comical relief. Any chemists in the audience?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word `Turf animals` or `Turf` could be used to describe something that is related to Ground/Land. Apart from `Turf`, `Terra-firma` could be used which means `Ground`.

Comment: This works great for me! I'm now using the term "Lawn" to describe the animals living near or on the surface. Turf pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: I recommend against this. "Lawn" has a strong connotation for a home's yard space, whether front or back yard. Look up "lawn care" to see this.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps "*afloat*" would do, though its colloquial hue may not fit well in a scientific study.

Comment: +1 Maybe also *floating* for attributive rather than predicative use.

Comment: Yes, "_floating_" would definitely do better than "_afloat_" in the context. Perhaps Horst can be more specific about how much not-submerged the concerned flora or fauna is (soaked but breathing air, just its lower part wet, nearly dry on a water lily or whatnot)

Comment: Afloat doesn't quite fit since the animals are living on the sphagnum plants and are not really floating. Rather clinging to the plants.

Comment: Hmm, then all I can think of is "_on water's edge_" - soaked or relatively dry according to the whims of the weather. But you were looking for an adjective, weren't you?

Comment: Sorry to see you deleted your account Chiron, you made some good contributions.

Answer (score 2):

Try ***surface***, as in *surface creatures*. -- [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/surface)

> *adj.* 1. working or operating on the top of the land or sea, rather than under the land or sea, or by air

Or maybe, ***surfaced***, as opposed to *submerged* -- [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/surfaced)

> *adj.* 2. Having risen or come up to the surface of the water or the ground
>   *"A gull will land on the back of a surfaced whale and rip at its flesh and blubber."*

Comment: Perhaps *surface-dwellers*.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it suits your purpose but 'emergent' could work better than *emerged*.

*Superficial* also means 'on or at the surface' but has the drawback of commonly being used to mean 'insignificant'.

Comment: Hello @Symone Atherton, welcome to **English Language & Usage**. Thanks for the response, but please read the question carefully when answering. The questioner mentioned _surficial_ [sic], not _superficial_. _Thanks!_

Comment: Thanks for the welcome @freeling10 I did read the question and was offering the word superficial because it means 'being at, on, or near the surface' in opposition to submerged.

Comment: Gotcha, @Symone Atherton. Thank you for the clarification and apologies for my incorrect assumption!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest intertidal fauna.

> The shallowest marine environments are those forming the transition between land and sea, and include intertidal habitats that are regularly exposed to air.
>   https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/agricultural-and-biological-sciences/intertidal-ecology

Comment: Use citations in answers, if you please.

Comment: Sorry. I'm not sure I know how to use citations. This is it, anyway: The shallowest marine environments are those forming the transition between land and sea, and include intertidal habitats that are regularly exposed to air.https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/agricultural-and-biological-sciences/intertidal-ecology

Comment: edit that citation into your answer if you will.  go to help section:   editing and citations if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

*Unsubmerged* isn't a word but might work in your story. After all, *unburrow* isn't a word, but even after 20 years of use in the Starcraft universe few have noticed.

I'm also finding that *nonsubmerged* is used often in the medical field, however, they sometimes hyphenate it into a phrase: *non-submerged*.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you would like the rather rare term [***subaerial***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/subaerial). This term is used chiefly in geology and botany, but I think could stretch to biology, as well. From Oxford Dictionaries:

> Existing, occurring, or formed in the open air or on the earth's surface, not under water or underground

Notably, this term is used in opposition with subaqueous, submarine, and *submerged*, as in this quote from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subaerial):

> Some pond plants have **subaerial** leaves as well as their **submerged** ones (water plantain, flowering rush,...).

Answer (score 0):

I first looked at "*superficial*" but that had too many other meanings that would be distractive. I came across "**external**" and "**exterior**" which might be useful to describe the fauna that dwell in the non-submerged aspect of a bog environment.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/external

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/exterior

Answer (score 0):

“Emersed”. It means to have something that is normally fully submerged to be out of water. Typically used to describe aquatic plants, but can be used for other subjects as well.

Comment: This would be improved with a supporting dictionary link for the definition.